# How do I disable/remove the State field in Magento2

Tags: magento2

Under Stores->Configuration->General->State Options

I unselect Switzerland. Then on the checkout page, the * for required field is not there anymore but the red message "Please select an option." still appears when I try to place an order without selecting a State.

"Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country" set to No and the field still shows up.

Any idea?

By the way, it seems that at least one Country must be selected in the "State is Required for" list.

Comment: Same problem - were u able to fix it already?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4117 | it is a bug, and it should be fixed in v 2.1